# Sonicwall route traffic through specific interface based on destination

Tags: routing, sonicwall, site-to-site-vpn

Here's my setup. I have **Sonicwall NSA 2400**, it is configured with **Percentage-Based WAN Load Balancing**.

- *LAN Interface*: X0
- *PRI Interface*: X1
- *T1 Interface*: X2

My question is, given any LAN->WAN traffic originating from the X0 network, what steps would I need to take in the configuration to route all traffice from LAN->WAN for a given destination (example [74.125.45.100]) through a specific interface, in this case... X1

I'm having to do this because I'm setting up a site-to-site VPN connection and the remote end will only allow one WAN IP address to accept the tunnel, so I am trying to force all traffic for that destination over a specific interface.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What I ended up doing was this:

Created a new Address Object under the **Network > Address Objects** menu. Click Add under "Address Objects", Put the name of the object, such as "Datacenter".

Zone assignment: WAN
Type: Network
Network: xx.xx.xxx.xxx
Netmask: 255.255.255.248

Click Add.

Next, Under *Network > Routing*

**Click Add.**

For Source, put in the LAN interface subnet, in my case I put in X0
For Destination, Select the Object we just created, "Datacenter"
Service, Any (you can do FTP, HTTP, Etc only, if you want)
Gateway: Default Gateway
Interface: X1 (WAN Interface you wish the traffic to pass through)
Comment: Datacenter over PRI

**Click "Disable Route when the interface is disconnected"** to allow for the WAN failover to still function, and traffic to reach the host if the interface is down.

Click Ok, and you're done!

Comment: For some reason, traffic is not passing over the tunnel, even though it is up and negotiated. Does anyone see a step I have missed to make all traffic pass over the tunnel ?


I created a VPN Policy:  DataCentertunnel  tunnel.domain.com (xx.xx.xxx.xxx)  
 xx.xx.xx.224 - xx.xx.xx.231
 ESP: AES-256/HMAC SHA1 (IKE)

Tunnel is up and active. If I tracert from the destination network (from WAN -> LAN) it only takes one Hop to reach destination, whereas if I tracert out from LAN->WAN it goes out over the public internet, versus the secure tunnel.